# how to write for loop with nested if statement in xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying the below code :-

```
return
            fn:concat (fn:string-join ((
              "somevalue.1.",
              "somevalue.2.",
              "some val 3",
              "some val4",
              $somevariable), " "), 
 for $i in $loopvar    
              if ((fn:exists($loopvar)) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 1)) then
              " where ( "  || $loopvar[i] || " and "
              else if(fn:exists($loopvar) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 0)) then
              " where " || $loopvar[i]
              else() )
```

This code is forming some part of a sql query in which i am trying to get the where conditions separated by "and". The variable $loopvar is of type string and it can have multiple values like column1=3, column2=4, column3=5...and so on. I want to check if this variable has some values then it form the query(as per the above code). However I am getting error in the fn:concat part:-

```
  fn:concat( fn:string-join( ("some val 1", "someval2"......" -- arg1 is not of type xs:anyAtomicType?
```

Can someone pls suggest where am I going wrong with the above piece of code?

Comment: The returned expression a in FLWOR construct must be prefixed with the `return` keyword. See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You list MarkLogic as a tag. If so, i would consider using the Optic API where you can more elegantly express your exact query.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues.

In your first `return` statement, you are returning the fn:concat(). You could have that as the end of the first FLWOR statement, but the second FLWOR is referencing the `$loopvar`. IF that is in the scope of the first FLWOR, then you need to ensure that the second FLWOR is one of a sequence of items returned in the first. Wrap both the concat and that for loop inside of parenthesis to indicate that you want to return a sequence of items that are all within the scope of that first FLWOR.

The error message is telling you that the `if` statement following the `for` is unexpected, because in that FLWOR statement you started a `for` loop and then have an expression that you want to `return`, so you need to add a `return` statement.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/#prod-xquery10-FLWORExpr

> (ForClause | LetClause)+ WhereClause? OrderByClause? "return" ExprSingle

Lastly, it seems you are iterating over the `$loopvar` sequence and attempting to use `$i` as an index in a predicate, but forgot the `$` for the `$i` variable i.e. `$loopvar[$i]`. However, unless the `$i` is a number, that probably won't select what you want. And if it is, it's still easier and more efficient to just use the `$i` variable:

```
(: I added some dummy variables, just to have a more complete example that would run :)
let $somevariable := "somevariable"
let $loopvar := ("a", "b", "c")

return (
  fn:concat (fn:string-join ((
              "somevalue.1.",
              "somevalue.2.",
              "some val 3",
              "some val4",
              $somevariable), " ")),
  for $i in $loopvar
  return
    if ((fn:exists($loopvar)) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 1)) 
    then " where ( "  || $i || " and "
    else 
      if(fn:exists($loopvar) and (fn:count($loopvar) > 0)) 
      then " where " || $i
      else() 
)
```

If you did want the position of the `$i` in your for loop, you can use the positional variable `at` expression and assign a position variable: `for $i at $j in $loopvar`
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/#doc-xquery10-ForClause

Comment: Where should I add the return ?\

Comment: in between the `for` and the first `if`. Take a look at the example code that I posted.

Comment: This piece of code that I am trying is already part of a return statement. Can I have two nested returns in xquery?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is really multiple FLWOR statements. Instead of returning a single item, you are returning a second FLWOR and so that for loop needs its own return.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you have a look again pls?